# Adobe Brackets IDE & CORS when developing locally

Tags: adobe-brackets

Since Brackets seems to start a new instance of Chrome, (how) can I make it start Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` option, in order to get around CORS problems when developing both the client & server on my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How to Use Brackets - Live Preview](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#live-preview):

> Live Preview currently has a few other important limitations:
>
> - It only works with desktop Chrome as the target browser.
> - Opening the Developer Tools in Chrome will close the live development connection.
> - Files must be inside your "project" (the root folder you currently have open in Brackets).
> - Only one HTML file can be previewed at a time. If you switch to a different HTML file in Brackets, the browser preview will switch to
>     that new page as well.
> - Updating pauses when the HTML is syntactically invalid (e.g. after you type '<' for a new tag but before you type the closing '>'). The
>     line number and Live Preview icon turn red in this case. Brackets will
>     resume pushing changes to the browser when syntax becomes valid again.

If you want to achieve what you want, edit the source code of Brackets IDE.

Comment: Some very good pints, thanks. But, rather than edit the Brackets source - every time they release a new version, it it would be better to request a change from the developers.

Comment: I agree with you. However I am not sure if you can achieve one browser for both normal browsing and live preview. Live Preview enabled remote debug of Chrome, which behave different from default chrome.

Comment: +1 Yes, but I can live without Chrome for day to day browsing. Right not, on Windows, I am using XAMPP for Apache and invoking Chrome with `--disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files`, which I would not want to do with my regular browser. But it seems to be the only way to debug. I have noticed, though, that Brackets' `live preview` starts a separate instance of Chrome, if I already have it running, so maybe they could add those parameters when starting it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't configurable yet in Brackets. We plan to [make launching Live Preview more flexible](https://trello.com/c/MYaUdJOR/508-live-development-w-custom-chrome-install-e-g-canary-portable-chrome-dartium) in the future, which would probably make it easy to configure the args Chrome is launched with - but that probably won't happen for a while.

If you wanted to custom-patch Brackets, as the other answer suggests, you'd need to modify the [native code that launches Chrome](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/blob/master/appshell/appshell_extensions_win.cpp#L342) and make a [custom build of brackets-shell](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/wiki/Building-Brackets-Shell). If you're pulling the source from Git, keeping up with Brackets updates isn't all that bad because you'll just be doing a `git merge` from upstream, which should preserve all your diffs.